# Mod_rewrite causing 500 and 508 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am having an issue with the rewrite mode on .htaccess file.

- Without .htaccess : no internal error but only the home page is accessible
- With .htaccess : all the site seems working but when I audit the site for SEO purpose I see couple of 500 internal server error and lot of 508 errors.

Any idea to fix that ? Even if the site looks OK the 5xx errors are a real problem for SEO.

Here is my htaccess file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

[Screen shot of the 5xx errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuEIZ.png)

Comment: Your htaccess looks ok. Have you tried setting WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php and then loading the specific pages causing the 500 error to see what the underlying php errors are?

Comment: I tried it but I can't find the debug.log in wp-content. I assume it means that I don't have any error ?? It is really strange as the website seems to works perfectly.
However the SEO audit displays those 5xx errors !

Comment: You have to make sure you have the debug log set in wp-config.php define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); and WP_DEBUG set to true and to view the error visually when you load the page make sure you have not set define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );

Also, have you tried these things with all plugins disabled etc?

Comment: wp-config.php didn't have WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY so I added this line and set it to true. Unfortunately I still have no debug.log file ...
I also disabled all the plugin = same problem